# How to check if a user is subscribed to a plan within a view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5, and I have created a very basic app.  The idea is to allow users to sign up for free, but after that point they must subscribe to one of two plans to use the additional functionality.

Using Laravel's built-in Auth the user, after login, is taken to /home (home.blade.php).  Here I want to check if the user is subscribed.

A method exists for this: `$user->subscribed()`, but how can I access that in my view?  `Auth` is available within the view, but `subscribed()` is not a method of it - I assumed (incorrectly) that `Auth` would contain a copy of the current logged in `$user`.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
@if (Auth::subscribed())
    You are subscribed!
@else
    You haven't subscribed yet
@endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@if (Auth::user()->subscribed())`

Try that.

According to http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/billing it should work.